# Adding header to ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to add a header to my ListView, but unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter cannot be cast to com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView$PinnedSectionListAdapter
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView$2.onScroll(PinnedSectionListView.java:91)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1340)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1762)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:678)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-28 01:35:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(17389):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cat, null);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    TextView header = new TextView(getActivity());
    header.setText("Header");
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);

    // ... adding objects to the adapter ...

    ArticleAdapter adapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, objects);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**I'm using pinned-section-listview library.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show layout file

Comment: what class does ArticleAdapter extends?

Comment: Pinned-section-listview does not support list headers for now.

Answer (score 1):

you try to add header 
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);

this causes listview to wrap adapter in one more adapter, `HeaderViewListAdapter`, whereas
library expects it's own adapter

```
// get expected adapter or fail
PinnedSectionListAdapter adapter = (PinnedSectionListAdapter) view.getAdapter();
```

You either fix used library, or post bug to it's author, or try not to use `addHeader`

Comment: Thank you. How should I fix this library? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I've made some modifications to original project, now we may add header to listview, but it lost all of its magnificient properties. Sections do not stick to listview's top anymore. If I get any luck with it, I'll let you know.
meantime, one more question- do you really need a header? It'll scroll with content. Consider addding simple textview on top of the listview.

Comment: First of all - Thank you very much. I need to put something in the top of the screen, and when you scroll down - it will stay at top (I mean, you won't see it after you scroll down).

Comment: You don't need a header then, you need textview above your list view